# How to know function is increasing function for multi variable case?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If there is no leading power from the multi variable function,

and if one of the partial derivative is negative

and other partial derivative is positive

How do I figure out whether the function is increasing or decreasing?

Comment: What do you mean by increasing or decreasing?

Comment: What does an increasing function of, say, two variables mean?  There is no total order (compatible with  vector space structure) on $\mathbf R^2$.

Comment: @Bernard I would like to figure out whether or not critical points in the multivariable case is min or max. Why does strictly concave imply critical point to be global max and why does strictly convex imply critical point to be global min?

Comment: All we have and need is *directional derivatives*. There we can speak about increasing/decreasing, and a critical point is local min/max iff it is so w.r.t. every direction.

Comment: That is a different problem and has nothing  to see with a monotonicity that doesn't make sense in this context. That said, the reason is  to be found in Taylor's formula at order $2$ for several variables. Basically, same reason as for the one-variable case, if you interpret the formula correctly.

Comment: @MathMA For classifying a critical point if it is a local max, a local min or something else see here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Second_derivative_test

Comment: @Bernard You made it clear thank you